# What is "+newcolor+" in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>The jQuery Example</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" 
     src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".inner").click(function () {
           var newcolor = $(this).css('background-color');
           $("#destination").wrap("<div class = 'newinner' 
              style = 'border:2px solid "+newcolor+"';></div>");
        });

     });
  </script>

  <style>
     .inner{ margin:10px;padding:12px;
        border:2px solid #666;

     }
     .newinner{ padding:20px;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click on any square below to see the result:</p>
  <div class = "inner" id = "destination">THIS IS TEST</div>
  <div class = "inner" style = "background-color:blue;">ONE</div>
  <div class = "inner" style = "background-color:green;">TWO</div>
  <div class = "inner" style = "background-color:red;">THREE</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What's the `+newcolor+`, I get its to copy the color of the clicked element, but what are the two `+`'s surrounding it?

Comment: This - `var newcolor = $(this).css('background-color');` and the +s are for string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

`newcolor` inside `+` refers to variable `newcolor` as described in this pic below.

[image: newcolor-mean]

The `+` sign is to use when you want to refer that `newcolor` is from the variable `newcolor` above it.

Don't forget to add single quote to close previous code, then add double quotes `"` before and after plus sign and add single quote to continue the previous code between +newcolor+

Answer (score 0):

For String concatenation.. Think of it this way:

```
 var str = "your string "+variable+"continues here"
```